# What is probability that 10th toss of a weighted coin is a head given that the first 9 tosses were heads?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Question : We are given a coin which lands on head with probability p such that  $ P(p \le x) = x^5$. Given that the first 9 tosses of the coin lands on head, what is the probability that the 10th toss is a head?

I have been practicing several probability problems, but having read this one I have no idea how to start. I am wondering if there is a way to determine a range on the value of p, but I do not have any idea how to use the information on the  previous tosses. I would appreciate someone giving me some hints/some resources I can use to learn about how to solve these types of question.

Comment: Are you assuming that the tosses are independent and identically distributed? In your $P(p\le x)=x^5$ what does $p$ and $x$ represent?

Comment: @Somos I read this question as that first some $p$ is randomly chosen with a process that has CDF of $x^5$, then a coin is flipped, and the coin has probability $p$ of coming up heads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One* way to handle such problems is to use the notion of [posterior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability).
We begin with a distribution for a parameter (in your case, the probability) and update it as we see more data (in your case, coin tosses).
The initial distribution is called the *prior* and the updated distribution is called the *posterior*.

Let $P$ be the probability that a coin flip is heads (a random variable).
Let $T_{i}$ be an indicator random variable that is equal to one if and only if the $i$-th toss is heads.
Fix a positive integer $n$ and let $\boldsymbol{T}=(T_{1},\ldots,T_{n})$.
By the definition of conditional probability,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(P\leq p\mid\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{t})=\frac{\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{t},P\leq p)}{\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{t})}.\label{eq:conditional_cdf}
\tag{conditional CDF}
\end{equation}
Let $\boldsymbol{1}=(1,\ldots,1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the vector of ones, corresponding to the event in which the first $n$ tosses were all heads.
Note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{1})=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\times5x^{4}dx=\frac{5}{n+5}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{1},P\leq p)=\int_{0}^{p}x^{n}\times5x^{4}dx=\frac{5p^{n+5}}{n+5}.
$$
Substituting these into the \ref{eq:conditional_cdf}, we get
$$
\mathbb{P}(P\leq p\mid\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{1})=p^{n+5}.
$$
The conditional density is obtained by differentiating:
$$
f_{P\mid\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{1}}(p)=\left(n+5\right)p^{n+4}.
$$
It follows that the probability that the ($n+1$)-th toss is a head is
$$
\int_{0}^{1}pf_{P\mid\boldsymbol{T}=\boldsymbol{1}}(p)dp=\frac{n+5}{n+6}.
$$

In the special case of $n=9$, this evaluates to $\boxed{14/15}\approx0.9\overline{3}$.

We can also use this to evaluate the unconditioned case (in which we have not seen any coin flips) by taking $n=0$.
In this case, the probability is $5/6\approx0.8\overline{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't read about posterior and prior distributions so I'll be sure to study on that. One question though: how did you get the the first integral equalling P(T=1). I see that the integrand is just the pdf times x^n but i don't recall a formula like that. I might be being silly but would it be possible for a bit of clarification on that line?

Comment: @minus123: It's the [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I was wondering if we can get the result directly from the moment we find $\mathbf{P}(T=\mathbf{1}^n)=n/(n+5)$. Then $\mathbf{P}(T=\mathbf{1}^{n+1})=5/(n+6)$. Then we can just use the definition of conditional probability to find $P(T_{n+1} =1 | T_1 = \cdots = T_n =1)$.